# System of high dimensional matrix equation

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I'm trying to solve the following system of matrix equations: `C-1.X1.C==B1`, `C-1.X2.C=B2` and `C-1.X3.C=B3`. The matrices involved are 9x9. I've been compiling for hours but still get no result. I was wondering why or even if the code is wrong.

Here is the code:

```
w1 = E^((2 \[Pi] I)/3);
w2 = E^((4 \[Pi] I)/3);

X1={{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}}

X2={{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0}}

X3={{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}

B1={{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1}}

B2={{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,w1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,w2,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0}}

B3={{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,w2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,w1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0}}

eqns={Inverse@c.X1.c==Ba2,Inverse@c.X2.c==Bb1,Inverse@c.X3.c==Bc1};

solution=Reduce[eqns,c\[Element]Matrices[{9,9}]]
```

Comment: I am confused. Your description uses B1,B2,B3 but your code uses Ba2,Bb2,Bc1. If I run
`cm=Partition[Array[c,81],9]; eqns={X1.cm==cm.B1,X2.cm==cm.B2,X3.cm==cm.B3}; cm/.ToRules[Reduce[eqns,Flatten[cm]]]`
 then I get a solution in a couple of seconds. BUT that solution worries me. Please think VERY carefully about what I've done and try to make certain I haven't made any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a linear system like so.

```
w1 = E^((2 \[Pi] I)/3);
w2 = E^((4 \[Pi] I)/3);

X1 = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
    0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1}};

X2 = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
     0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

X3 = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
     0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

B1 = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
     1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
    0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -1}};

B2 = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, w1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
    0, w2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0}};

B3 = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, w2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
    0, w1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0}};

cmat = Array[c, Dimensions[X1]];
linpolys = 
  Flatten[Join[X1 . cmat - cmat . B1, X2 . cmat - cmat . B2, 
     X3 . cmat - cmat . B3]] /. 0 :> Nothing;
cmatsol = cmat /. (sol = First@Solve[linpolys == 0, Flatten[cmat]])

(* During evaluation of In[174]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.

Out[176]= {{c[1, 1], c[1, 2], c[1, 3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, c[2, 6], 0, 0, c[2, 9]}, {0, 0, 0, 0, c[3, 5], 0, 0, c[3, 8],
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, c[3, 5], 0, 0, c[3, 8]}, {c[1, 1], 
   E^(-((2 I \[Pi])/3)) c[1, 2], E^((2 I \[Pi])/3) c[1, 3], 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, c[2, 6], 0, 0, c[2, 9], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
   c[2, 6], 0, 0, c[2, 9], 0}, {0, 0, 0, c[3, 5], 0, 0, c[3, 8], 0, 
   0}, {c[1, 1], E^((2 I \[Pi])/3) c[1, 2], 
   E^(-((2 I \[Pi])/3)) c[1, 3], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

Check:

```
In[177]:= linpolys /. sol

(* Out[177]= {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0} *)
```

Also:

```
invcmat = Inverse[cmatsol];

RootReduce[
 Together[
  Flatten[Join[invcmat . X1 . cmatsol - B1, 
    invcmat . X2 . cmatsol - B2, invcmat . X3 . cmatsol - B3]]]]

(* Out[202]= {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I take the first line as the definitions of the equations and neclect the code. I doubt that invertible solutions exist in general, because the  direct equations produce mainly zeros

```
    eqns1 = { X1 . c == c . B1, X2 . c == c . B2, X3 . c == c . B3};
    solution = 
    c -> MatrixForm[Solve[eqns1, c \[Element] Matrices[{9, 9}]][[1, 1, 2]]]
```

$$c\to \left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 c_{1\, 1} & c_{1\, 2} & c_{1\, 3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{2\, 6} & 0 & 0 & c_{2\, 9} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{3\, 5} & 0 & 0 & c_{3\, 8} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{3\, 5} & 0 & 0 & c_{3\, 8} \\
 c_{1\, 1} & e^{-\frac{1}{3} (2 i \pi )} c_{1\, 2} & e^{\frac{2 i \pi }{3}} c_{1\, 3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{2\, 6} & 0 & 0 & c_{2\, 9} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{2\, 6} & 0 & 0 & c_{2\, 9} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{3\, 5} & 0 & 0 & c_{3\, 8} & 0 & 0 \\
 c_{1\, 1} & e^{\frac{2 i \pi }{3}} c_{1\, 2} & e^{-\frac{1}{3} (2 i \pi )} c_{1\, 3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

```
     Det[c /. Solve[eqns1, c \[Element] Matrices[{9, 9}]][[1]]]
```

$-1)^{2/3} \left(-3 (-1)^{2/3} c_{1\, 1} c_{1\, 2} c_{1\, 3}
   c_{2\, 9}{}^3 c_{3\, 5}{}^3+3 c_{1\, 1} c_{1\, 2} c_{1\, 3}
   c_{2\, 9}{}^3 c_{3\, 5}{}^3+9 (-1)^{2/3} c_{1\, 1} c_{1\, 2}
   c_{1\, 3} c_{2\, 6} c_{2\, 9}{}^2 c_{3\, 8} c_{3\, 5}{}^2-9
   c_{1\, 1} c_{1\, 2} c_{1\, 3} c_{2\, 6} c_{2\, 9}{}^2 c_{3\,
   8} c_{3\, 5}{}^2-9 (-1)^{2/3} c_{1\, 1} c_{1\, 2} c_{1\, 3}
   c_{2\, 6}{}^2 c_{2\, 9} c_{3\, 8}{}^2 c_{3\, 5}+9 c_{1\, 1}
   c_{1\, 2} c_{1\, 3} c_{2\, 6}{}^2 c_{2\, 9} c_{3\, 8}{}^2
   c_{3\, 5}+3 (-1)^{2/3} c_{1\, 1} c_{1\, 2} c_{1\, 3} c_{2\,
   6}{}^3 c_{3\, 8}{}^3-3 c_{1\, 1} c_{1\, 2} c_{1\, 3} c_{2\,
   6}{}^3 c_{3\, 8}{}^3\right)$